# IPv4 entries L3 switch

Tags: cisco, networking

I am preparing the spec for L3 switch. I decided to buy the C9300L series switch, but I found out that the C9300L series has no IPv4 routing table entries. What does that mean? What is the impact of not having IPv4 routing table entries in an IPv4 network?

Comment: Routing is disabled by default. So have you enabled it in the first place? At least one port must be configured for routing - have you done that? If not, I'd recommend checking out the configuration guide. 9300 config guides (a guide per IOS version) are at https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/switches/catalyst-9300-series-switches/products-installation-and-configuration-guides-list.html

Comment: I have yet to buy it. On the datasheet, I only found IPv6 routing entries. But according to https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-9300-series-switches/nb-06-cat9300-ser-data-sheet-cte-en.html#Table7, the Catalyst 9300 series has 32,000 (24,000 direct routes and 8000 indirect routes).  This could answer my question.

Comment: Aha, you were a bit unclear there. Yes, that does answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Catalyst 9300 series supports pretty large routing tables. You can feed them by using (depending on license) RIP, OSPF, EIGRP, IS-IS, BGP, or static entries, of course.

Maximum sizes:

```
Total number of IPv4 routes (ARP plus learned routes)  32,000 (24,000 direct routes and 8000 indirect routes)  
IPv4 routing entries                                   32,000 
IPv6 routing entries                                   16,000
```

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-9300-series-switches/nb-06-cat9300-ser-data-sheet-cte-en.html#Table7

Comment: IPv4 routes vs IPv4 entries, isn't there any difference between them? IPv4 routing entries (32,000 ) are not put explicitly in the datasheet unless we are saying IPv4 routes and IPv4 entries are the same concepts.

Comment: You were asking about *IPv4 routing table entries* which is what is shown above. What kind of other IPv4 entries are referring to now?